# How to activate newly created conda environment in google colab -- conda activate <env_name> not working

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I just installed miniconda in Google Colab because my experiment needed to have different versions of certain libraries which are provided by colab, like tensorflow 1.4.0 was needed.

I installed miniconda as per steps given in various tutorials like this -- https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522?gi=47dbd407577c

conda installation was successful now I created a new environment, Now I wanted to activate that environment so that I can start working on it by installing libraries. But the problem comes when using `conda activate new_env` , it gives following error/message:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
> use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run
>
> $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
>
> Currently supported shells are:
>
> - bash
> - fish
> - tcsh
> - xonsh
> - zsh
> - powershell
>
> See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
>
> **IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running
> 'conda init'.**

I do not know what to write in 
Another problem is whatever I write, even if that's correct how do I restart my shell for changes to take effect ? How do I restart a terminal in colab ?

I am not able to enter my newly created environment.
Please help.

Thanks,
Pranay